# setcookie for little time doesn't work in non-firefox

Tags: php, cookies, cross-browser

While testing some scripts, I've noticed, if expiration time is little (not zero) - cookie isn't available in Chrome, Opera, IE.

Example:

```
<?php
// setting cookie for 5 minutes
setcookie( 'cookie1' , 'Test', time()+60*5 );
echo $_COOKIE['cookie1'];
// yeap (it should display it only with refresh of page - I know:)
?>
```

In Firefox - I see the word Test (after opening and refreshing the page).

But in other browser - I don't see this.
If I change time to `time()+60*100` for example - it works fine in all browsers.

What's the reason of this?

UPD:

From Chome Dev Tool (sorry, don't know how Chrome firebug is called):

```
Date:Sun, 22 May 2011 10:29:59 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=99
Server:Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Set-Cookie:Maslo123=Test; expires=Sun, 22-May-2011 10:34:59 GMT
```

Date is early than 'expires';

Comment: Did you check the actual *Set-Cookie* header field value? Your server might have a wrong system time.

Comment: Yes, the time is wrong on server. (Few hours delaying) But how does this reflects on different browsers?

Comment: @Innuendo: Um, could be a bug. But it would require more information to tell that.

Comment: you shouldn't rely on cookies for short term/time storage, if you read the manual (specificity here) http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#96813 your see the pitfuls with using cookies

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone: The statement you’ve linked to is wrong. The *Expires* value is an absolute time value as it refers to GMT no matter where the client/server is located. But it’s still true that an absolute time value fails if a machine does not use the correct time.

Comment: 2 Lawrence Cherone, I don't need to keep cookie for 5 minutes. In real task I need a few days - but while testing - I set 5 minutes, and noticed this problem (now, I need the decision just for curiosity - in real task I have big cookie time and problem doesn't occur)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we have already acquired that your server’s time is wrong by few hours and thus the cookies are already expired.

The reason why Firefox still stores the cookie might be that it detect the odd time difference between the server and the client and uses the difference between the *Date* value and the *Expires* attribute value to determine the cookie expiration date.

These issues are also the reason why latter RFC standards like the current [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) prefer the relative time value of delta seconds.

Comment: So Firefox checks only server time, but other time checks and local time too while getting cookie, and it occurs that this cookie is expired?

Comment: @Innuendo: I don’t know it with certainty. But it seems to be the only reasonable reason. Did you check how long that cookie is valid in Firefox?